# creating dispatcher for mapping functionalities

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

I have an array of different object types (about 15 different types) , they are coming from 3rd party system.
For every type I need to make different transformation.
My original thought is to make some interface with transform function and for every type make a class and run it's own implementation.
But like this I will need to make a really big if statement that checks the object type and make the mapping.

I am trying to learn something new here, so my question is there other ways to deal with this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered the possibility of using a [Visitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)?

If you combine the visitor pattern with the use of `dynamic`, you could get a pretty simple implementation without any `if` or `switch` statements, or having to manually create a Type Dictionary with delegates, or similar alternatives.

Using `dynamic` you can avoid implementing the "*accept*" part of the design pattern, which I assume is useful to you since these are external types you have no control over.

Meaning, you create something like this:

```
public interface IVisitor
    {
        void Visit(OneType element);
        void Visit(AnotherType element);
        ....
    }
```

You implement that visitor, and can later call the implementation using:

```
visitor.Visit((dynamic)objectToTransform);
```

You would probably have to handle for exceptions regarding not having an appropriate overload for the `Type`.

That would solve the part of the problem related to executing a separate method for each type.
Now, depending on what you specifically need to do with each one, if you need automatic property mapping then [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) could be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a lookup of type and transformation, similar to [Java Front Controller pattern.](http://java.sun.com/blueprints/patterns/FrontController.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but have a look at [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) (or aother mappers). It allows you to easily define rules to map types to other types.

Comment: but AutoMapper will also need if statement , because I need to specify what objects I am running it on.